# Navigation through a Laravel filebag

Tags: laravel, blueimp

I am using a medium editor image insert plugin, which has a dependency of bluimp image upload.

For the server side, I am trying to get the image before uploading it.

If if do:

dd($request->files)

I get this:

```
FileBag {#45
#parameters: array:1 [
"files" => array:1 [
  0 => UploadedFile {#30
    -test: false
    -originalName: "2015-07-17-018.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 240817
    -error: 0
    path: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php"
    filename: "phpiGBKNo"
    basename: "phpiGBKNo"
    pathname: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpiGBKNo"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpiGBKNo"
    aTime: 2016-05-09 14:39:11
    mTime: 2016-05-09 14:39:11
    cTime: 2016-05-09 14:39:11
    inode: 37419151
    size: 240817
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 501
    group: 80
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
]
}
```

As you can see there is an image there, but I cannot seem to get the single image no matter what I do. Tried $request->files[0] / files->UploadedFile etc and nothing I have done will return that image.

Answer (score 4):

You can manipulate file with appropriate methods only:

```
$file = $request->file('photo');

$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files

Also, you can use [additional methods](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html).

Comment: One of those question where as soon as I posted I realised how to do it :) Thanks though shall mark as the right answer! :)